# Monthly Year over Year Growth Rate using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My goal is to get the Year-over-Year Growth. I have tried group by, arrange, and the mutate function, but the Year-over-Year Growth column is not producing the right result(That is why I am try to get to get a dataset where I have alternating years).

```
Data:

date         store  city   measurement
2010-01-01   a      LA     150
2010-01-10   b      NY     160
2010-01-20   c      SE     10
...
# There is no 2011-01-01
#2011-01-01   a     LA     900
2011-01-10   b      NY     170
2011-01-20   c      SE     20
...
2012-01-01   a      LA     900
2012-01-10   b      NY     170
2012-01-20   c      SE     20
What I am trying to get:

date         store  city   measurement   YOY
2010-01-01   a      LA     150           ?
2011-01-01   a      LA     900           0
2012-01-01   a      LA     900                    
2010-01-10   b      NY     160           0.0625          
2011-01-10   b      NY     170           0
2012-01-10   b      NY     170    
2010-01-20   c      SE     10            1
2011-01-20   c      SE     20            0         
2012-01-10   b      NY     20 
2010
2011
2012
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`arrange` the data by `city` and `date` and for each `city` calculate `YOY` by subtracting the previous value of `measurement` with the current value dividing by the previous value.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
            mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
            arrange(city, date) %>%
            group_by(city) %>%
            mutate(YearoverYear=(measurement-lag(measurement))/lag(measurement))
```

Comment: Hi @RonakShah. I updated the data from above. But when I tried the code above, I am not sure if the YOY column is performing the calculations correctly(Like in my updated dataset, the date 2010-01-01 is present while the date 2011-01-01 is not present). Before using the lead function, I used the lag function.

Comment: @SL42 Your data in the post is not consistent, hence it is difficult to compare the answer with it. For eg - `NY` all the 3 value in your input is 160 whereas in your output you have shown it as 160,170, 170. Which one is true? It is therefore important provide data in a reproducible format using `dput` which we can copy-paste into our session. What is the formula that you use to calculate YOY growth?

Comment: This is the formula I have used. YearoverYear=(measurement-lag(measurement))/lag(measurement,1). I will fix the data above.

Comment: So wouldn't using `mutate(YearoverYear=(measurement-lag(measurement))/lag(measurement))` in the last line of my answer fix the issue?

Comment: That does not work as well. I am checking by comparing the previous  year(2010) well in this case, the present year(2011). I am assuming it has to do with the lag function or the lead function. My date column is a POSIXCT format.

Comment: @SL42 It is not possible for us to know that your date column is of `POSIXCT` format if you don't mention it or share your data. Please add `dput(head(df, 10))` to your post.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I think mutate(YearoverYear=(measurement-lag(measurement))/lag(measurement)) with the code above worked. It was my understanding of the lag function.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the correct version.

Comment: If you arrange by date, won't you get a daily % change, not yearly? Getting YOY from daily time series data seems tricky. Two approaches: (1) make sure you have data for *all* dates (fill in any that are missing, perhaps using ```tidyr```'s ```fill```), sort by date in the MMDDYYYY format not the usual YYYYMMDD format, and use the lag formula as discussed. Or (2) summarize the data by week, month, or year (perhaps by selecting the measurement from the earliest or latest day of that period, and then use the lag formula passing in the appropriate n (e.g., 12 to count back 12 months).

Comment: I think OP has only one row for each year and each city. They don't have daily data but yearly data for each city.